# Bootstrap select turns from dropdown into input field on AJAX - js.erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-select

Having a small issue - when I am trying to update the view results via AJAX in Ruby on Rails (js.erb) ie. when I update/render the form via AJAX, selectpicker turns into just simple input, hence it just disappears from the view. Could someone suggest what I need to do to fix that?

```
= form.input_field :id, :include_blank => "Some text...", collection: @some_ids, 
class: 'selectpicker', "data-style" => "btn", 
"data-width" => "100%", :selected => object.id, :id => "some_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to rebind if the select is dynamically added to the page. You should add:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

to your `js.erb` file after the content is added to the DOM to initialize elements with the `selectpicker` class as select pickers.

Comment: I have tried that and $('.selectpicker').selectpicker("render"); as well $('.selectpicker').selectpicker("refresh"); nothing makes the difference for some reason

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What html markup is generated in the page by your haml? Maybe that is the issue, but it's hard to say without knowing what `@some_ids` contains. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: ah man, thats it. some some stupid mistake. placed @some_ids at the wrong place - all works now! Appreciated for some direction :)